# Indexing two fields in mogo: timestamp and text

Tags: mongodb, indexing

I do much find requests on collection like this:

```
{'$and': [{'time': {'$lt': 1375214400}},
          {'time': {'$gte': 1375128000}},
          {'$or': [{'uuid': 'test'},{'uuid': 'test2'}]}
         ]}
```

Which index i must create: compound or two single or both?

uuid - name of data collector.
time - timestamp

I want to retrieve data, collected by one or few collectors in specified time interval.

Comment: An `$or` operator with a single term doesn't make sense.  What are you trying to query for here?

Comment: @JohnnyHK, it may contain 1 or 2-10 items in different requests.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query would be better written without the `$and` and using `$in` instead of `$or`:

```js
{
  'time': {'$lt': 1375214400, '$gte': 1375128000},
  'uuid': {'$in': ['test', 'test2']}
}
```

Then it's pretty clear you need a compound index that covers both `time` and `uuid` for best query performance.  But it's important to always confirm your index is being used as you expect by using [`explain()`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/cursor.explain/).